# How to run $(document).on 'ready' with Turbolinks 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

In a Rails app I have a coffeescript function that should run after the DOM has loaded

```
$(document).ready ->
  # do some stuff
```

It used to be that I could ensure these functions also work across Turbolinks page refreshes by editing as follows

```
$(document).on 'ready page:change', ->
  # do some stuff
```

I've just upgraded to Rails 5 and Turbolinks 5, and these functions are no longer being called correctly.

After much searching, I've tried numerous variations, including

```
$(document).on 'ready', ->
$(document).ready ->
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
$(document).on "page:load", ->
$(document).on "page:change", ->
# and as suggested by the [Turbolinks readme][1]
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
```

I have also tried these with and without [jquery.tubolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) installed, and with the turbolinks-compatibility patch suggested [here](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/61).

I must be missing something obvious! What is the correct syntax to ensure functions run after the DOM is loaded for both page loads and Turbolink loads?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official turbolinks github documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads):

> In many cases, you can simply adjust your code to listen for the turbolinks:load event, which fires once on the initial page load and again after every Turbolinks visit.

So it would like this is pure js:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // ...
})
```

or like this in coffeescript:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  # ...
  return
```

Comment: thanks @Mark, I have tried to get things working with this event. While the documentation states that the `turbolinks:load` event is triggered on "initial page load and again after every Turbolinks visit", I think my problem is that the event appears to only be triggered after every Turbolinks visit. Do you have any idea why the initial page load would not trigger the event, or how to debug this?

Comment: @AndyHarvey interesting. Okay, if you put a `console.log("here");` statement as the first line in your `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->` event, and then refresh the page, do you see the output in the console? Also, are there any errors in the console?